# Python: How to write int32 to csv files?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a numpy array to a csv file using `csv.writer` object. But after writing I got the string representation of my numpy array!

```
with open('res.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
   csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
   csv_writer.writerow(['Id', 'Solution'])       
   csv_writer.writerows(y_pred)
```

some output lines of the `res.csv` are:

```
Id,Solution
1,0
2,1
3,1
4,0
...
```

But they stored as strings!

Actually I'm trying learning python through [Kaggel site](http://www.kaggle.com) but after I submit my `res.csv` file the leader board says that my entries are in the `string` format and must be in `int32` format.

How can I fix it?

Comment: CSV files are Strings indeed, maybe you should not include the header? Try removing the `csv_writer.writerow(['Id', 'Solution'])` line.

Comment: Yes that works without the header! but the header must be there. If I remove the header code, I have to add it to the res.csv file manually!

Comment: can you try to use [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) instead?

Comment: I tried that but I got a # sign before Id in its entry?!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
numpy.savetxt('res.csv', y_pred, fmt='%d', delimiter=',', newline='\n', header='Id, Solution', footer='', comments='# ')
```

this outputs:

```
$ cat res.csv
# Id, Solution
1,0
2,1
3,1
4,0
```

you can change the format with the the format string set by `fmt` keyword. see [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html). You can change the comments symbol as well.

Comment: I tried that(but with fmt='%d') but I got a # sign before Id in its entry?!

Comment: set `comment=''` but maybe you want to comment out the header? if kaggel is using [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) then it will skip the header if it's commented out, and then it will automatically load the numbers as `int32`, otherwise, you need to provide `skiprows` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
np.savetxt('test.txt', a, fmt='%d', delimiter=',',
           header='Id,Solution', comments='')
```

If have to specify `comments=''` to avoid the default comment "`#`" prepended to the beginning of the header (and footer) string ([see here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)).